# a question which about the associative law

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I tried to understand how do I get the second line from the first one;
I know it's about the associative law, but couldn't figure it out.
If someone knows how to explain this to me it would be really helpful.

[image: The question is here]

Comment: Do I have to click into your link to find out what your question is? I think I'll pass.

Comment: Hint: $D\cup D'$ is the whole space for ever subset $D$.

Comment: @bof: Have some charity -- new users with no rep _cannot inline images_, and he may not know how to type the formulas without images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is primarily about the *distributive* law. $\cup$ distributes over $\cap$, in the same way that $\cdot$ distributes over $+$ in elementary algebra, so
$$ (a+b)\cdot(c+d) = a\cdot c + a\cdot d + b\cdot c + b\cdot d $$
corresponds to
$$ (a\cap b)\cup(c\cap d) = (a\cup c) \cap (a\cup d) \cap (b\cup c) \cap (b\cup d) $$

First you use the distributive law from the right to get
$$ (a\cap b)\cup(c\cap d) = (a\cup (c\cap d)) \cap (b\cup (c\cap d))$$
Then use it from the left on each of $a\cup(c\cap d)$ and $b\cup (c\cap d)$ separately.

---

*Caveat:* Usually in set algebra one thinks of $\cap$ as "morally corresponding" to multiplication and $\cup$ as corresponding to addition, but set algebra is more symmetrical in that there are distributive laws both for $\cap$-over-$\cup$ and for $\cup$-over-$\cap$. In this case it is the latter we need.